# Distinct does not work with select clause

Tags: ruby, postgresql, ruby-on-rails-5

I have 2 tables

```
class DepartmentBudget < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :budget_details, dependent: :destroy
end

class BudgetDetail < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :department_budget
end
```

Each department have budgets for specific period of time. and each department have many budget_details which consist of all credit and debit entries and maintains remaining balance.

Issue is I want to apply sorting on department budget based on balance of latest budget detail.

```
DepartmentBudget
  .joins(:budget_details)
  .select('budget_details.balance, department_budgets.*')
  .order("budget_details.balance ASC")
  .distinct
```

I have implemented above query but it's returning **duplicate records**. the issue is with **select** clause if I remove select then distinct works, but I have to use select with distinct.Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: `based on last record of budget detail's balance attribute`  This phrase is confusing. An attribute can't have the last record. Only a table can have the last record having multiple attributes. Please, clarify the question

Comment: I have more clarified post

Comment: If you need to apply sorting based on the last associated `budget_details` record, then the `budget_details.created_at` column should be somehow involved in the query to find the last created record. Don't you think so?

Answer (score 0):

```
DepartmentBudget.includes(:budget_details).order("budget_details.balance ASC")
```

Comment: While this might answer the authors question, it lacks some explaining words and links to documentation. Raw code snippets are not very helpful without some phrases around it. You may also find [how to write a good answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer) very helpful. Please edit your answer.

Answer (score 0):

It's not clear what your purpose is, but if we assume that your SQL is logically correct then you should use `GROP BY` clause and an aggregate function to achieve your purpose.

```
DepartmentBudget.joins(:budget_details)
                .select('department_budgets.*, MIN(budget_details.balance)')
                .group('department_budgets.id')
                .order("MIN(budget_details.balance) ASC")
```